# the meaning of "the cloak of respectability wore gradually thinner"

Tags: meaning-in-context

*And as they read, little by little **the cloak of respectability wore gradually thinner**, the pretence of secrecy was dropped, the name of their master was discreetly avowed and quietly praised.*

Source: H. R. Trevor-Roper: Niccolo Machiavelli. In Joseph Frank (ed.) Modern Essays in English, p. 24.

This is an excerpt from the text on N. Machiavelli. In the paragraph, from which I cites only this sentence, the author sets forth how Machiavelli was in the middle of the 16th century becoming an acceptable political thinker and how many famous individuls started reading him and thereby they legitimized his work. Given the context I have the problem with the metaphor  "the cloak of respectability wore gradually thinner" which (if I understand it properly) asserts the opposite: increasing the inrespectability. But this seems to be against the sense of the context. What does exactly the mentioned metaphor mean?

Comment: Please cite the author.  What is "the text"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [cloak](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cloak) is normally a loose fitting garment that is worn over the clothes and covers the whole body. From this idea comes a metaphorical meaning "something that hides, covers, or keeps something else secret".

**a cloak of respectability** is an idiomatic way of saying that somebody pretends to be respectable in order to conceal wrong behaviour.

The expression [wear thin](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wear-thin) is another fabric-related idiom. If an item of clothing is worn regularly, the fabric gets progressively thinner: it becomes partially transparent, and so can no longer conceal what is underneath.

Comment: Thak you for your answer. Can I paraphrase the meaning in the sense that people did not have to hide their respect for his writing.

Comment: @bart-leby: exactly.

Comment: @JavaLatte according to your definition of "cloak of respectability" has a negative connotation, doesn't it? So, please, see whether it is correct or not. The sentence means: something that had been hidden in order that the person seemed respectable was being uncovered and he was losing his respectability. So how is it concludeable as: people did not have to hide their respect for his writing? I feel baffled.

Comment: @sina: the author's use of the cloak metaphor is unusual.  He means to say that there was no longer a need to pretend to abhor M's ideas. The cloak is not really wearing thin, it is being taken off. I also find his use of the word "pretence" a little strange.

Comment: @TRomano Thank you a lot. I was thinking maybe there was something wrong with my understanding. Because the meaning you mentioned came to my mind, but then I read the answer and... . As I found out this is a translated and edited writing. I am suspecting a somehow word by word translation or something like that, if I am not wrong.

Comment: @TRomano I found it here https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=the+cloak+of+respectability+wore+gradually+thinner. Unfortunately The whole text is not avalabe.

Comment: @sina, if you do a little research about Count  Machivlelli, you will understand why people might try to pretend that they do not read that kind of thing. It's the political equivalent of pornography. Then, as they slowly realise that everybody else is also reading it,  then they first admit it, then eventually proudly tell everyone that they read it.

Comment: @JavaLatte Maybe I am slow in understanding it. I apologize you then. I get what you mean. My problem is with interpteting this expression, "the cloak of respectability wore gradually thinner". You mean the readers were pretending his works were respectable although they believed the other way around. But then they realised there was nothing wrong with his works so there was no need to pretend that way.... . I feel this expression or idiom, whatever you call it, is not used for this mean: people do not have to hide their respect. Because by this expresdion we say we

Comment: Pretend respect althuogh sth is not respectful, don't we?

Comment: @sina, as I said before, people were **pretending that they had not read** Machiavelli's book, though they were actually reading it in secret- **under the cloak of respectability**.  Then they realised that everybody else was reading it, and they no longer needed to hide the fact that they had read it. You cannot fully understand the sentence if you do not know anything about Machiavelli. Start off by reading this... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niccol%C3%B2_Machiavelli

Comment: @JavaLatte I read it. He had a bad reputation because of a book, the Prince, he wrote, and some ideas he had about politcs and etc. But afterwards people gradually appreciated his book, or books more and this bad reputation disappeared.Am I right?

Comment: @JavaLatte sorry for bothering you a lot. I decided to ask the question that formed for me after reading this question:-D

Comment: If it was "the cloak of disrespectability" I would not have any problem with it.