# "Cloak of secrecy"

Tags: meaning, metaphors

> Ministers tried to cover up the truth by hiding under a cloak of secrecy.

My problem is with "a cloak of secrecy"?

Also with the meaning of all "a cloak of ..." phrases.

Is secrecy compared to cloak? I mean, is it a metaphor?

Comment: It is like the [Cone of Silence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_of_Silence), though point of this comedy bit was that it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **cloak** is an over coat used as protection against bad weather since it completely covers up the wearer.

The use of "cloak" is as a metaphor for hiding or covering *something*.

The action of **cloaking** is usually used to "change the appearance" of *something* by covering it up with *something else*

[image: here]


In the case of your sentence

> Ministers tried to cover up the truth by hiding under a cloak of secrecy.

> **Ministers tried**
>   *Ministers attempted (unsuccessfully in the context)*
>
> **to cover up the truth**
>   *to hide the truth (something which was bad or embarrassing)*
>
> **by hiding under**
>   *structured this way it refers to the ministers hiding something so it could not be seen*
>
> **a cloak of secrecy.**
>   *the ministers kept an umbrella of secrecy amongst themselves*

if the text said

> by hiding ***it*** under

it would be referring to the "truth" being hidden

Comment: Here covering secracy? Seems meaningless!

Comment: You know my post is edited. I asked for paraphrasing the sentence.

Comment: Not **covering** secrecy, but the cloak is made of "secrecy", covering *something*, like a "cloak *(made)* of wool" covering the wearer.

Comment: Oh! So "cloak of respectability" in bart-leby means a cloak made of respectability?

Comment: Yes, it would mean that, so *something* covered with the "cloak of respectability" might mean that it should be respected.  It is another metaphor, can be used for all adjectives (though some might not make sense...).

Comment: No, something covered with a cloak of respectability would make it **look** like it should be respected on the surface ... when it often times is not.

Comment: That's possible too, more context would be needed, but certainly they want it to look respectable.

Comment: That question is making me crazy. I straggeled a lot to understand what the whole sentence of which this phrase is a part mean. But still have problem:-((

Comment: By the way, I love this cloak in the picture:-))

Answer (score 3):

A cloak is a covering. "Of" in this case is the meaning "made from".

A "cloak of secrecy" is a covering made out of "secrecy".

This sentence is stating that, because the ministers didn't want anyone to know the truth of the situation, they told everyone that it was secret information that couldn't be given out.

The implication in the sentence is that this might not have been really true, but that the ministers were just trying to protect themselves.

This isn't always the case, so it's not a necessary interpretation.

> Nancy's party was kept under a *cloak of secrecy* until we all jumped out and yelled "surprise". Because we'd done such a good job, she'd never realized the party was happening!

This really just means that everyone had to pretend that the party wasn't happening (around Nancy) so that she wouldn't find out before hand.

Comment: What about the source of forming this question, "And as they read, little by little the cloak of respectability wore gradually thinner, the pretence of secrecy was dropped, the name of their master was discreetly avowed and quietly praised.".

Comment: I would presume that this was a group of villains and that their master was some sort of super villain posing as a heroic sort to the outside world... that this scene is when those people discover that this "respectable" person is actually not respectable at all... which is what they want.

Comment: The cloak made of respectability disappeared, not proper in this context. The pretended respectability disappeared, again not proper, because his works was not appreciated at first, so there was not any respect, pretended or real, to disappear.

Comment: It's metaphor, right... so it's not actually "made of"... what it's saying is that (for the readers being referenced) they saw through the cloak ("wore thinner" - a thin cloak can be seen through)... it's only on the surface that this person is respectable... Think about Superman. **On the surface**, he's a mild-mannered reporter, clutzy, bespectacled... he wears a cloak of dorkiness... but it covers up the fact that he's an extra-terrestrial being with amazing powers. This guy... he's the exact opposite. He looks like a respectable person on the surface but is actually evil underneath.

Comment: Peter I have way difficaulty understanding thoes sentences,but now I can understand the phrases made cloak. Thank ypu a lot.

Comment: @Catija, sina's quote is about people reading "the Prince" by Machiavelli. At the time, it would have been something like reading "Lady Chatterley's Lover" in the 1930's: people read it in secret and pretended they hadn't, until it became clear that everybody else had also read it. It comes from this question: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/90497/the-meaning-of-the-cloak-of-respectability-wore-gradually-thinner/90500#90500

Comment: What about this: let's imagine this sentence is refering to a time N. Machiavelli had been respectable even after wrting the book "The Prince". But after a while that people read more the book and understood it as an unrespectable work, that superficial respect wore off, i.e. , the cloack of respectability wore away. What do you think? Could I finally get it?:-)

Comment: @Catija, JavaLatte, I found an irony in the last part "his name was discreetly avowed and quietly praised". It somehow proves I am right. It may mean that he was objected on the serface, but quietly prased (maybe by polititions or the objectors themselves). After that his superficial respectability disappeated and he was objected, his believers could not exalte him openly. By I am right, I am refering to my comment before this one

Comment: @JavaLatte, Catija, Peter, You can be prode of yourselves for being perfect people. Thank you for helping me to finally understand the sentence that was eating me from the moment I saw it.